# user register rest API status 500 when user already exsit in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

[image]

I have issue when already user exist then status error 500

Answer (score 0):

We you retrieve something you should use get method. Please check postman method.

Correct retrieve user syntax:

```
GET /wp/v2/users/<id>
```

Example Request

```
http://demo.wp-api.org/wp-json/wp/v2/users/<id>
```

Comment: thanks for reply but we use create user API and in case we create new user and this name already exist then this error display

Comment: If you are check a user is exist then you should use call back function for that

Comment: issue is still same

Comment: You have to create business logic for that there is no api to check is user exist.